# Table with gap between cmidrule's (extra space between two columns)

Tags: tables

> **Example of my final solution based on Werner's suggestion can be found at the  end of this question.**

I would like to make a table that looks about as this one:

[image: Example table created in excel]

I can get most of this to work with the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}\centering
\begin{tabular}{l c c c c}
\toprule
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Text1} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Text2} \\ 
    \cmidrule{2-3} \cmidrule{4-5}
    & A & B & A & B \\
    \midrule
Foo & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Foo matter}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

which gives me this result:

[image: Latex table]

So far the only solution (that kind of works) that I could come up with is to add an empty column between column 3 and 4. I was however hopping that there is an easy solution that allows me to directly add some space between the two columns.

[This solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24258/add-extra-space-only-between-two-specific-columns-of-a-tabular-without-adding-ex) seems to be pretty close to what I would like but causes some problems with the last three columns (they do not appear to be cantered). Adding

```
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}{@{\extracolsep{3cm}}c@{\extracolsep{0pt}}}%
```

to the preamble and changing begin tabular to

```
\begin{tabular}{l c c C c}
```

gives me:

[image: So close]

That is close but not quite what I need.

I did also find a few solutions to insert a space between rows but could not transfer them to columns: [Row Space 1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26690/how-to-add-extra-spaces-between-rows-in-tabular-environment) and others.

> **Solution based on answer by Werner**

The solution for me is mostly what Werner suggested. I have only added values for how much the lines should be trimmed on either side. 
To get:

[image: The table I wanted]

I used:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}{@{\extracolsep{3cm}}c@{\extracolsep{0pt}}}%

\begin{document}

\begin{table}\centering
\begin{tabular}{l c c c c}
\toprule
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Text1} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Text2} \\ 
    \cmidrule(l{2pt}r{2pt}){2-3} \cmidrule(l{2pt}r{2pt}){4-5}
    & A & B & A & B \\
    \midrule
Foo & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Foo matter}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

---

Comment: I am little bit confused: You want extra space between rows but add it at the columns?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer No, I do want space between columns. In english I always confuse the two. It's terrible. Sorry about that! I corrected now in the question.

Comment: How large should the space between the relevant columns be? 3cm is quite large!

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Maybe 1em would be the best. But that will basically depend on the final usage. So I would like to understand the principal behind a solution.

Comment: I think, Werner made a good proposition, see below

Comment: I would suggest you post your solution as an extra answer, as it is easier to upvote. You can credit Werner anyway, or make it community wiki.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proper centering with cmidrule and multi- row and column](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/156219/proper-centering-with-cmidrule-and-multi-row-and-column)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The only way to *break* the horizontal rule would be to insert a separate column (as you suggest), or to marginally trim the `\cmidrule`s using the optional `(..)` specification:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l c c c c}
  \toprule
  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Text1} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Text2} \\
  \cmidrule{2-3} \cmidrule{4-5}
  & A & B & A & B \\
  \midrule
  Foo & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{l c c c c}
  \toprule
  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Text1} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Text2} \\
  \cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5}
  & A & B & A & B \\
  \midrule
  Foo & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{l c c c c c}
  \toprule
  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Text1} & & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Text2} \\
  \cmidrule{2-3} \cmidrule{5-6}
  & A & B & & A & B \\
  \midrule
  Foo & 1 & 2 & & 3 & 4 \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Adding space in the column specification using

```
\begin{tabular}{l c c@{\hspace{1cm}} c c}
```

inserts `1cm` between columns 3 and 4, but would require you to correct alignment when using `\multicolumn` *without* providing the gap.

I don't think inserting an empty column is that bad. You could actually control the width of the column to provide a finely-tuned spacing of the `\cmidrule` separation. Something like

```
\begin{tabular}{l c c c@{\hspace{1cm}} c c}
```

Would give a gap of exactly `1cm` between columns 3 and (now) 5.

Comment: Adding a blank column to small tables is no problem for smaller tables. If they however do get bigger I feel having a empty column just impairs the readability of the raw latex table even further. Also, I am wondering this approac could be used for tables created from file using `pgfplotstables`. But maybe there is a way to create an empty column in there somewhere.

Comment: I most liked your second table suggestion so I had a look at the booktabs documentation and found that it is possible to pass a value to either `l` and `r`. I have now changed the entries for the `\cmidrule` to `\cmidrule(l{2pt}r{2pt}){2-3} \cmidrule(l{2pt}r{2pt}){4-5}` which is exactly what I wanted (well, I will have to replace the {2pt} with proper values but that should be ok!

Answer (score 1):

See this page - there is an optional argument in cmidrule already!

[Proper centering with cmidrule and multi- row and column](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/156219/proper-centering-with-cmidrule-and-multi-row-and-column)